How to calculate the covariance of a subset of MLE parameters?
Let $X_1, \dots, X_n $ be i.i.d. random vectors with a density function $ f(x_i \mid \theta^*) $, where $ \theta^* = (\theta_1^*, \theta_2^*) $ is partitioned into two subvectors $ \theta_1^* $ and $\theta_2^* $. Under standard regularity conditions, by the asymptotic normality of the MLE, we know that:
$$
\sqrt{n} \begin{pmatrix} \hat{\theta_1} - \theta_1^* \\ \hat{\theta_2} - \theta_2^* \end{pmatrix} \overset{d}{\to} N \left( 0, I_0(\theta^*)^{-1} \right),
$$
where $I_0(\theta^*) $ is the Fisher information matrix evaluated at the true parameter $ \theta^* $, and thus the asymptotic covariance matrix is $ I_0(\theta^*)^{-1} $.
I would like to calculate $ \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta_2} - \theta_2^*) $ directly, rather than computing the full covariance matrix $ \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta} - \theta^*) $. While I understand that $ \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta_2} - \theta_2^*) $ is simply a submatrix of $ I_0(\theta^*)^{-1} $, the inverse of $ I_0(\theta^*) $ is difficult to compute in my problem.
My question:
Is there an alternative approach to compute $ \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta_2} - \theta_2^*) $ directly without having to invert $ I_0(\theta^*) $? For example, could a modified version of the asymptotic normality proof for MLEs be applied to just $ \hat{\theta_2} $? See proof here.
In particular, I have considered performing a Taylor expansion for the score function $ \frac{\partial \log f(X_1, \dots, X_n \mid \theta_1^*, \theta_2)}{\partial \theta_2} $, but I encountered a problem: the score function evaluated at $ (\theta_1^*, \hat{\theta_2}) $ is not zero, so the first step in the proof does not work as it does when expanding around $\theta^* $.
Additionally, under what conditions on the relationship between $ \theta_1 $ and $\theta_2 $ in the likelihood function can we deduce that $ \text{Cov}(\hat{\theta_2} - \theta_2^*, \hat{\theta_1} - \theta_1^*) = 0 $? This would allow me to simply invert $I(\theta_2^*) $ to obtain $\text{Cov}(\hat{\theta_2}-\theta_2^*)$.
Thank you for your insights!
